XSLT:Sort issue when using the key field
I have an issue while sorting LuLineItem where I need to sort it when its corresponding Iden/IdenValue, where IdenType=OCC1 is repeating in another LuLineItem, then based on Idenvalue, where Identype=OCC2, we need to do the sorting.
My XSLT is not giving correct sequence, Please review it once.
Input: IdenValue=1234 in first LULineItem where identype=OCC1 is not repeating, but IdenValue=4567 is repeating in second and third LULineItem, so we need to sort LULineItem based on IdenValue where IdenType=OCC2
<SBD>
    <SBDH>
        <Field1> value1</Field1>
    </SBDH>
    <rAdvice>
        <LULineItem>
            <UnitIden>
                <CCode>
                    <SSCC>32101</SSCC>
                </CCode>
            </UnitIden>
            <CLine number="1">
                <cIIden>
                    <ntig>00000000000000</ntig>
                    <Iden>
                        <IdenValue>1234</IdenValue>
                        <IdenType>OCC1</IdenType>
                    </Iden>             
                    <Iden>
                        <IdenValue>XYZ</IdenValue>
                        <IdenType>OCC2</IdenType>
                    </Iden>
                </cIIden>
            </CLine>
        </LULineItem>
        <LULineItem>
            <UnitIden>
                <CCode>
                    <SSCC>543857</SSCC>
                </CCode>
            </UnitIden>
            <CLine number="2">
                <cIIden>
                    <ntig>00000000000000</ntig>
                    <Iden>
                        <IdenValue>4567</IdenValue>
                        <IdenType>OCC1</IdenType>
                    </Iden>
                    <Iden>
                        <IdenValue>BCD</IdenValue>
                        <IdenType>OCC2</IdenType>
                    </Iden>
                </cIIden>
            </CLine>
            <PO>
                <dReference>
                    <CreatorIden>094832</CreatorIden>
                    <cOwner>
                        <nlg>0000000000000</nlg>
                    </cOwner>
                </dReference>
            </PO>
        </LULineItem>
        <LULineItem>
            <UnitIden>
                <CCode>
                    <SSCC>32109</SSCC>
                </CCode>
            </UnitIden>
            <CLine number="3">
                <cIIden>
                    <ntig>00000000000000</ntig>
                    <Iden>
                        <IdenValue>4567</IdenValue>
                        <IdenType>OCC1</IdenType>
                    </Iden>
                    <Iden>
                        <IdenValue>3109</IdenValue>
                        <IdenType>OCC3</IdenType>
                    </Iden>
                    <Iden>
                        <IdenValue>ACD</IdenValue>
                        <IdenType>OCC2</IdenType>
                    </Iden>
                </cIIden>
            </CLine>
        </LULineItem>
    </rAdvice>
</SBD>


Desired output:
<SBD>
     <SBDH>
        <Field1> value1</Field1>
    </SBDH>
    <rAdvice>
        <LULineItem>
            <UnitIden>
                <CCode>
                    <SSCC>32101</SSCC>
                </CCode>
            </UnitIden>
            <CLine number="1">
                <cIIden>
                    <ntig>00000000000000</ntig>
                    <Iden>
                        <IdenValue>1234</IdenValue>
                        <IdenType>OCC1</IdenType>
                    </Iden>
                    <Iden>
                        <IdenValue>XYZ</IdenValue>
                        <IdenType>OCC2</IdenType>
                    </Iden>
                </cIIden>
            </CLine>
        </LULineItem>
        <LULineItem>
            <UnitIden>
                <CCode>
                    <SSCC>32109</SSCC>
                </CCode>
            </UnitIden>
            <CLine number="3">
                <cIIden>
                    <ntig>00000000000000</ntig>
                    <Iden>
                        <IdenValue>4567</IdenValue>
                        <IdenType>OCC1</IdenType>
                    </Iden>
                    <Iden>
                        <IdenValue>3109</IdenValue>
                        <IdenType>OCC3</IdenType>
                    </Iden>
                    <Iden>
                        <IdenValue>ACD</IdenValue>
                        <IdenType>OCC2</IdenType>
                    </Iden>
                </cIIden>
            </CLine>
        </LULineItem>
        <LULineItem>
            <UnitIden>
                <CCode>
                    <SSCC>543857</SSCC>
                </CCode>
            </UnitIden>
            <CLine number="2">
                <cIIden>
                    <ntig>00000000000000</ntig>
                    <Iden>
                        <IdenValue>4567</IdenValue>
                        <IdenType>OCC1</IdenType>
                    </Iden>
                    <Iden>
                        <IdenValue>BCD</IdenValue>
                        <IdenType>OCC2</IdenType>
                    </Iden>
                </cIIden>
            </CLine>
            <PO>
                <dReference>
                    <CreatorIden>094832</CreatorIden>
                    <cOwner>
                        <nlg>0000000000000</nlg>
                    </cOwner>
                </dReference>
            </PO>
        </LULineItem>
    </rAdvice>
</SBD>

XSLT I used is below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="rAdvice">
      <xsl:for-each select="LULineItem">
           <xsl:sort select="CIIden/Iden[IdenType='OCC2']/IdenValue" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
   
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>


Please review it once

Based on your comments and your question I now think you want something like
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="rAdvice">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="LULineItem" group-by="CLine/cIIden/Iden[IdenType='OCC1']/IdenValue">
        <xsl:sequence select="sort(current-group(), (), function($l) { $l/CLine/cIIden/Iden[IdenType='OCC2']/IdenValue })" />
      </xsl:for-each-group>    
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>

Example fiddle that seems to have the desired result.

Both the grouping key and the sort key look wrong because CLine elements do not have Iden as an immediate child. I haven't looked at the exact logic, but perhaps (in both cases) Iden should be cIIden/Iden.
But that doesn't feel right either. From LULineItem you are selecting CLine children and grouping them, but there is only one CLine child, so grouping has no effect.
As far as I can see, your input contains three LULineItem elements, and your output contains the same three LULineItem elements but in a different order. So the processing of an LULineItem element should simply be to copy it unchanged to the output. Control of the order needs to come at the upper level. I would expect something like
<xsl:template match="rAdvice">
  <xsl:for-each select="LULineItem">
    <xsl:sort select="...."/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

but I can't work out from your description what the sort key is supposed to be.
Sorry if I've missed something.

This is a case where xsl:perform-sort can do the job of the xsl:for-each and xsl:copy-of, too.

ok i updated the xslt, where its not yet sorting as expected, not sure why its still giving same input as output

Please don't make substantive changes to a question after it has been answered. It makes it impossible for anyone (including me!) to follow the thread. You can add further information to the question, making clear that it is an addition, but a change that makes nonsense of an existing answer is not acceptable. It's better to start a new question.

Here's another approach, using a key as a way to count the number of LULineItem which have a particular value of CLine/cIIden/Iden[IdenType='OCC1']/IdenValue.
The LULineItem elements are sorted by a value which is taken from either:

their occ1 identifier if the number of LULineItem elements with that identifier is exactly 1,
otherwise (if there are > 1 LULineItem elements with that identifier) the OCC2 identifier

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:key match="LULineItem" name="LULineItem-by-OCC1-value" use="CLine/cIIden/Iden[IdenType='OCC1']/IdenValue"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="rAdvice">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:perform-sort select="LULineItem">
        <xsl:sort select="
          (
            CLine/cIIden/Iden[IdenType='OCC1']/IdenValue[
              count(key('LULineItem-by-OCC1-value', .)) = 1
            ],
            CLine/cIIden/Iden[IdenType='OCC2']/IdenValue
          )[1]
        "/>
      </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>

